# If $ x=(x_1,x_2)^T \ \ and \ \ y=(y_1,y_2)^T $

Tags: linear-algebra

If $ x=(x_1,x_2)^T \ \ and \ \ y=(y_1,y_2)^T $ , show that

(i) $ x^T x\geq 0 $

(ii) $ x^Ty=y^Tx $

**Answer:**

$ x^Tx= x \cdot x=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix}=x_1^2+x_2^2 \geq 0 $

**Am I right . Any help with the notation $ (x_1,x_2)^T=[x_1,x_2] $  ?**

Comment: Your answer is right! What help do you need with the notation? $(x_1,x_2)^T$ means a column vector so like $x_1 \choose x_2$.

Comment: I think the help needed would be the $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct for (1). For (2):
$$
x^Ty = x\cdot y = \sum_i x_iy_i = \sum_i y_ix_i = y\cdot x = y^Tx
$$

Note that you can write:
$$
x^Ty=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}
           =x_1y_1+x_2y_2=\sum_jx_jy_j=x\cdot y
$$
using, for instance, in $\LaTeX$

```
$$ x^Ty=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}
       =x_1y_1+x_2y_2=\sum_jx_jy_j=x\cdot y$$
```

Personally, I think any of $(x_1,x_2)=[x_1\;x_2]$ is fine. 
(I like the look of $[x_1\;x_2]$ or $[x_1,x_2]$ i.e. `$[x_1\;x_2]$ or $[x_1,x_2]$` better).